# How to change finger pointer to crosshair?

Tags: javascript

```
var eles = document.querySelectorAll('li.level a'),
    i;

for (i = 0; i < eles.length, i++) {
  eles[i].onclick = function() {
    //...
  };

}
```

now, i want to make when the mouse over the a text, i want to change  finger pointer to crosshair.so i make the above code to the following: but it doesn't work.

```
for (i = 0; i < eles.length, i++) {
      eles[i].onclick = function() {
        //...
      };
eles[i].onmouseover = function(this) {
        this.style.cursor="crosshair";
      };

    }
```

the code doesn't work, how to correct it? thank you

if i only want to change it by javascript with the above code, how should i do?

Comment: Changing the cursor can also be done with the CSS-property `cursor`

Comment: if i only want to change it by javascript, how should i do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you have will work if you get rid of the argument. Since `this` is a reserved word you can't name an argument `this`:

```
eles[i].onmouseover = function() {
    this.style.cursor="crosshair";
};
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/jamesallardice/4426W/1/).

However, as has already been stated in the comments, a better approach may be to just use CSS:

```
li.level a:hover {
    cursor: crosshair;
}
```

Here's an [example of the CSS version](http://jsfiddle.net/jamesallardice/4426W/).

---

*Side notes*

- You also have a syntax error in your `for` loop:

  ```
  for (i = 0; i < eles.length, i++) // Wrong
  for (i = 0; i < eles.length; i++) // Right (semi-colon, not comma)
  ```
- It's generally better practice to use `addEventListener` instead of setting the `onsomevent` property. You can use `attachEvent` to support old versions of IE.

Comment: I also think the css approach is the correct here -> http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_cursor.asp

Comment: James Allardice，if i want to using attachEvent or addEventListener to replace onmouseover?how should i do?

Comment: @user1188320 - I suggest you spend some time reading and learning about basic DOM methods. MDN is a good place to start. Here's the article on `addEventListener`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.addEventListener

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem in code. remove this from arguements.

```
eles[i].onmouseover = function(/*this*/) {
        this.style.cursor="crosshair";
      };

    }
```